# encryption algorithms iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, encryption, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hi am using soap and want to add encryption algorithm for user validation and have no idea. My app is almost complete just stuck in that. If any one know about that then tell me. Thanx in advance...

Comment: For what purpose? Storing on device or for service logon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to support data encryption/decryption in an iOS app is through the sdk support. Take a look at [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/01introduction/introduction.html) guide from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MD5 algorithm when sending information for logon but you need to modify server side too